# Redirecting posts in Wordpress to a specific page

Tags: posts, pages, templates, loop

I created a page so that it would appear in my navigation menu. This page would however be my posts page (i.e. all posts would go here) and would also be my front page.

I am unable to find anything other than editing the 'Home' in the theme file (none of the themes I tried had the 'Home' editable).

In other words, I'm looking for something that would redirect all of my posts as a stream into my homepage that also has a link in the navigation menu.

I tried looking at a lot of places for help in this, however I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of navigation menu do you mean? One that you manage through the admin menu screen or one that creates itself based on pages?

Comment: The one that creates itself based on pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with just having the front page show blog posts like it does by default. No need to make empty pages and redirect and all that. In the theme file that contains your navigation (quite likely `header.php`), look for something that looks like this:

```
<ul>
<?php wp_list_pages( /* maybe some stuff here */ ); ?>
</ul>
```

You can add a list item before `wp_list_pages()` that points to home, e.g.

```
<li<?php if ( is_home() ) echo ' class="current_page_item"'; ?>><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>">Home</a></li>
```

There's also a conditional in there that will add the `current_page_item` class if you're on the home page with blog posts.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds wonderful! Just another query though. The code that you were talking about looks like this.
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=<h2>Pages</h2>' ); ?>
How do I incorporate a list item when it's not in an <ul> tag of its own?

Comment: `wp_list_pages()` does not output the `<ul>`, so it must be in there somewhere. Check your final HTML output to see if it's there. Can you link to the site?

Comment: It's still under development, I've somehow managed the end result. Thanks so much!